# Shuffle characters within string R

Tags: r, regex

I would like to move one part within a string to the beginning of the string. Please see example below. Can this be done using regex?

in:

```
c("41_exo","47_exo","48_exo")
```

out:

```
c("Exo_41","Exo_47","Exo_48")
```

Comment: Do you mean "swap" 2 underscore separated parts of a string and capitalize the letter one? Please be specific, provide exact requirements, and what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with regex.

```r
vec <- c("41_exo","47_exo","48_exo")
# using base R
gsub("(.*)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1", vec)
#> [1] "exo_41" "exo_47" "exo_48"
# using stringr
stringr::str_replace_all(vec, "(.*)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1")
#> [1] "exo_41" "exo_47" "exo_48"
```

Created on 2018-07-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Or *without* regex:

```
sapply(
  strsplit(vec, "_"),
  function(x) {
    paste0(toupper(substring(x[2], 1, 1)), substring(x[2], 2), "_", x[1])  
  }
)
[1] "Exo_41" "Exo_47" "Exo_48"
```